# c# Add transparent label on web eye web cam control

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, webcam

I have been working on an Iron Man hud. I am using WebEye to access the web cam... now i have to add label over the web cam control but the label is not transparent 
I have tried every control but cant use the transparency function..

Here's my code

```
 foreach (WebCameraId camera in webCameraControl1.GetVideoCaptureDevices())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(camera));
        }

        if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[0];
        }

        ComboBoxItem i = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

        try
        {
            webCameraControl1.StartCapture(i.Id);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Do something if u want to
        }
```

please help!!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Winforms have no real support for transparency. When you set the background color of a label to Color.Transparent what happens is that it uses it's parent control's background to mimic transparency.

Comment: Is there any other way through which I can achieve this?? @ZoharPeled

Comment: Probably. You can create your own true transparent label, but it does have it's drawbacks. I'll try to find an example for you this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, creating a transparent label will not help over video. If your `webCameraControl` is not a sealed class, you can inherit it to add the text directly on it's surface, like I did with this picture box:

```
public partial class LabledPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public LabledPictureBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region properties

    // I needed to override these properties to make them Browsable....

    [Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Font;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Font = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public override Color ForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ForeColor;
        }

        set
        {
            base.ForeColor = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion properties

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        // This is actually the only code line that's needed to add the text to the picture box
        TextRenderer.DrawText(pe.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, pe.ClipRectangle, this.ForeColor);
    }
}
```

The most important thing here is the line right after `base.OnPaint` - That line actually paints the text directly over the surface of the already painted control.